# Conditional Joint Density Function $(Y | X) \sim \mathcal{N}(x, 1)$ and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ whats $f(y | x)$

Tags: probability

Conditional Joint Density Function: $(Y | X) \sim \mathcal{N}(x, 1)$ and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ whats $f(y | x)$

Since $X \sim \mathcal{N(\mu, \sigma^2)}$ then $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\{ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x - \mu)^2 \}$.

... I would think $(Y | X) \sim \mathcal{N}(x, 1)$ so $f(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\{ -\frac{1}{2}(x - x)^2 \} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\{ 0 \}$ but I believe this is not the case? In my lecture notes

$$f(x, y) = f(y|x)f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \exp\{ -\frac{1}{2} ((y-x)^2 + x^2) \}$$ It seems like they did $f(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\{ -\frac{1}{2}(\color{red}{y} - x)^2 \}$. So somehow $x$ became $y$ (colored red)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f(y\,|\,x)$ is a function of $y$, so in the p.d.f. substitute the "**dummy**" $x$ with $y$ and $\mu$ with $x$, we get: $$f(y\,|\,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y - x)^2}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ in the expression
$$
Y|X\sim\mathcal{N}(x,1)
$$
has a different meaning than the $x$ in the expression
$$
(1) \ \ \ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2}.
$$
In the first expression, you want the pdf of $Y$ (not $X$!!!) given $X$. In this case, the value $x$ of $X$ is "known" and so enters into the pdf as a *parameter*, not as the value of some random variable whose value is unknown. Think of $x$ as known here.

But in the second formula, the standard formula for the $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$ density, $x$ is the value of the random variable whose pdf you want to know. Now if $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, then we could write $Y$'s density as
$$
(2) \ \ \ f(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(y-\mu)^2/2}.
$$
And if we had some other random variable $S\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, we could write $S$'s density as
$$
f(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(s-\mu)^2/2}.
$$
You get the idea.

So if $Y|X\sim\mathcal{N}(x,1)$, what's the pdf of $Y|X$? Well, you want to use formula $(2)$ above, not $(1)$, because you're looking for $Y$'s pdf, not $X$'s! You used formula $(1)$ and ended up with rubbish because you're looking for $Y$'s pdf, not $X$'s. So just substitute $\mu=x$ and $\sigma^2=1$ in $(2)$ and you get the pdf of $Y|X$:
$$
f(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y-x)^2/2}.
$$

Hope this helps!